# How do I add a downloadable PDF in the Microsoft's web app bot which is integrated with Microsoft's QnA maker service?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

In IBM Watson Assistant, I have an option of entering some code that will allow the user to download a PDF while conversing with the Assistant.

Is there a similar option in QnA Maker, such that, upon clicking on some sentence or link, the user would be able to download a particular PDF or any document?
I wish to integrate this Microsoft QnA Maker with Microsoft web app bot

I went through the documentation, but couldn't find anything. I went through many stackoverflow posts, but that didn't help either.

Comment: The Bot Framework doesn't handle anything with attachments apart from making them available to the channel (Slack, kik, Teams, etc). The channel client itself is responsible for rendering or handling what to do with attachments when they are available/sent. As @matt-stannett has mentioned, if you are just wanting to change how the links behave, but still have user interaction on clicking the link; his answer is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out of the box but you might be able to still achieve the functionality that you want (depending on the user's browser).

You could add the [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) attribute to your links where you want files to be downloaded. That way when a user clicks the link and it opens in a [compatible browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download) the default action will be for a file download to be initiated, rather than navigating to the page.

There is a short blog post on this [available here](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-download-attribute/). But what is boils down to is changing your answer from:

```
My answer with a <a href="....">link</a> in it.
```

to

```
My answer with a <a href="...." download>link</a> in it.
```

If the channel that you are visiting doesn't support rendering HTML and you have to achieve this using Markdown then I'm afraid I don't have the solution for you.